# Когда Google Play выплачивает денежные средства?

Tags: google-play, платежи

Есть аккаунт разработчика, и платное приложение. На аккаунте было 170$.

Добавил способ оплаты 2 января. 8 января отправили первую выплату,которая составляла 47$. Потом выплата еще одна была 16 января (59$). После 16 января выплат по сегодняшний день небыло больше.

Сейчас на аккаунте 110 $, и я не понимаю когда теперь будет выплата, и сколько выплатят? Как разобраться в этом?. Почему после 8 января след. платеж был 16 января? А потом почти месяц затишье.. Гугл платит 1 раз в месяц, или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[График ежемесячных выплат](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/137997?hl=ru)

> По всем обработанным заказам, а также заказам, за которые вернули
>   средства или отозвали платеж с первого числа до конца данного месяца,
>   выплаты совершаются 15 числа следующего месяца. Обратите внимание, что
>   для появления операции в выписке по вашему счету может потребоваться
>   ещё несколько дней. Подробную информацию о сроках обработки
>   электронных платежей можно узнать в своем банке.

**Правила выплат и необходимый минимальный баланс**

> Данные на странице **Настройки платежей** в Play Console обновляются в
>   течение 24 часов после выплаты.
>
> Google не производит выплаты по выходным и праздничным дням. Например,
>   если заказ оформлен в четверг, пятницу или субботу, то выплата будет
>   произведена в понедельник. Если понедельник – праздничный день, то
>   выплата будет произведена во вторник.
>
> К моменту выплаты на вашем балансе должно быть не меньше:
>   1 доллара
>   США, если вы получаете платежи в местной валюте;
>   100 долларов США, если вы получаете платежи в долларах США банковским переводом.

[Сумма выплаты](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2700656)

> Для получения выплаты в конце платежного периода на вашем счете должно
>   быть не менее 100 долларов США. Максимальная сумма не ограничена, если
>   она не указана в вашем аккаунте.

**График выплат**

> Выплаты банковскими переводами осуществляются [по тому же графику](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/137997),
>   что и остальные платежи.